# Characters not encoded properly in a Website on plesk

Tags: php, html, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have already searched on stackoverflow for this issue and i have implemented all the solutions that i have read.

I am developing a Spanish Website, all the Spanish chars like for example `á` and `ñ` are displayed like � if i upload the website in a server with Plesk and Mysql 5.7 .

**On localhost and if i upload the website on another server i don't have any encoding problems**. Here there is the example with the working link:

[Example of page with the Spanish chars](http://testgraphic.altervista.org/utf8.php)

My implementations:

- `<meta charset="UTF-8">` after `<head>`
- All the database, the tables and the columns are encoded with `utf8mb4` as indicate on stackoverflow:

[UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

- Before every query there is `mysqli_set_charset( $conn,'utf8mb4')` and the query is always executed without errors.

This is what i see on the website on Plesk:

[image: Website in Plesk]

Comment: See "black diamond" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored